# ElementFinder(ContextAware) class instantiation with SeleniumLibrary/robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

With Selenium2library, the following works fine (python):

```
browser = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('Selenium2Library')._current_browser()
elements = ElementFinder().find(browser, locator, tag)
```

But the same fails for SeleniumLibray, on investigating figured out that ElementFinder class in Seleniumlibrary has a parameter that needs to be passed (ctx).  Could someone help me out what needs to be passed to instantiate ElementFinder() class?

Answer (score 0):

The context is the instance of the library itself.

Example:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from SeleniumLibrary.locators import ElementFinder

def custom_keyword(locator):
    selib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")
    ef = ElementFinder(selib)
    element = ef.find(locator)
    return element
```